# Samsung's demonstration of THz communication

Tags: digital-communications

I have recently found articles about Samsung's demonstration of THz communication.

1. [Samsung demonstrates 6G THz wireless communication](https://www.inavateonthenet.net/news/article/samsung-demonstrates-6g-thz-wireless-communication)
2. [Samsung demos 6G using Terahertz spectrum](https://www.fiercewireless.com/tech/samsung-demos-6g-using-terahertz-spectrum)

They announced they built a prototype of the THz link, but it was the end-to-end 140 GHz wireless link using a fully digital beamforming solution. It is unclear to me, how it can be a "demonstration of THz communication" if it is 140 GHz.

The band from 300 GHz to 1 THz was suggested for 6G, as I know. I can not understand how 140 GHz link can be "THz communication".

Do I understand it wrong?

Comment: It is probably a proof-of-concept of a part of the 6G technology - not yet implemented at the more ambitious final operation frequency.

Comment: *140 is nice because not as high as 300*? *latency could potentially be reduced to one-tenth*? Tuning out.

Answer (score 0):

140 GHz is certainly not a THz, nor in a "6G range", 300 GHz or more.
(Some articles say that 6G will be 300 MHz-1 THz range. But is there any official specification in this Feb, 2023?)

As the articles say, Samsung just did demonstration of their THz link prototype. If the prototype was successful, they would already demonstrate 300 GHz or more bandwidth.
However, they could not yet build fully working prototype for 300 GHz or more bandwidth.

In other words, **they are making THz-link, but still in the level of 140 GHz.**

In my view, to stay within the frontiers of 6G, they decided such business decision to publish the news.

On the other hand, some competitors are releasing better results, though details are still hidden behind the curtain.

- 270-320 GHz: [Rohde & Schwarz and Fraunhofer research 6G at THz frequencies](https://embeddedcomputing.com/news/rohde-schwarz-and-fraunhofer-research-6g-at-thz-frequencies)
- 360-430 GHz: [Chinese lab achieves major achievement in wireless communication](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202201/1245197.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

> *It is unclear to me, how it can be a "demonstration of THz
> communication" if it is 140 GHz.*

You are getting baffled by marketing vs engineering truths. In marketing, the THz band is this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-terahertz/#:%7E:text=Terahertz%20(THz)%20radiation%20is%20generally,%2C%20and%20near%2Dmillimeters%20wave.), so, on a marketing basis, 140 GHz is within the THz band. But, are marketing people interested in truth or accuracy? Is someone trying to sell you something?

More of the same story: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.toptica.com/technology/technical-tutorials/terahertz/terahertz-properties#:%7E:text=The%20terahertz%20range%20refers%20to,3%20mm%20and%2030%20%CE%BCm.).

So, depending on who you speak to or where you look, it can mean many things and this puts it firmly in the marketing BS realm.